# Register event for all elements in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to register same event for all `<button>` elements in a div as i have 24 of them so i tried to use Jquery's `$.each()` in this way and it reads the div as the element instead of the button

```
$("#online-hours").each(function () {
    var element = this;
    $(element).click(function () {
        if ($(element).hasClass('btn-success')) {
            $(element).toggleClass('btn-success');
            $(element).addClass('btn-danger');
        } else if ($(element).hasClass('btn-danger')) {
            $(element).toggleClass('btn-danger');
            $(element).addClass('btn-success');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle with your HTML and Jquery please?

Comment: If you have multiple elements with same ID, you can select only first one. Use tag or class instead.

Comment: @Regent the div contains 24 button elements with no ids

Comment: @DanielEugen then what for do you use `.each()` and `this` at all? What is the logic in it? Select buttons, not `div`.

Answer (score 4):

if the id is on the container, you should be calling

```
$("#online-hours button").each(function () {
```

Comment: @vals It will be very sad to see code `$("#online-hours button").each(function () {  var element = this; $(element).click(function () {` and so on.

Comment: @Regent I agree it's not the kind of code style that I like. I just focused on the problem as stated. Leave the OP first discover how to make it work, and later get to good practices ...

Answer (score 0):

You better use event delegation instead of "each":

```
$("#online-hours").on("click", "button", function (event) {

    var $button = $(event.currentTarget);

    // Do something with your $button;

});
```

Comment: By the way, you can use `this` instead of `event.currentTarget`

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var list = div.querySelectorAll('button');
var i = list.length;
while(i--){
    list[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) { //doesn't have to be click
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

EDIT if you mean button tags use my answer if you mean input tags with type='button' use baao's

Answer (score 0):

the way you have written your code looks like you have `same id multiple time` which should not be better use class.
you can try with:

```
$("button").each(function () {
//code here............
});
```

or

```
$(".online-hours button").each(function () {
    //code here............
    });
```